# How to iterate over Java 8 String Stream and append line to String?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a method using the code below based on other resources how to iterate a file using a Java 8 stream:

```
String result = "";

try (Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(Paths.get("/home/user/file.txt"))) {
   stream.forEach(System.out::println);
} catch (IOException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

However, I want to save the lines to += a string, instead of console.

I have tried these 2 below but neither pass IDE validation:

`stream.forEach(thisString -> result += thisString);`

`stream.forEach(result += this);`

`stream.forEach(result::this);`

What is the proper way to append each result from the foreach loop to a String object?

Comment: `result =   stream.collect(Collectors.joining());`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Hadi J* has given you the answer in his [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61957123/how-to-iterate-over-java-8-string-stream-and-append-line-to-string#comment109582273_61957123)

```java
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class FileJoin {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String result = "";

        try (Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(Paths.get("/home/user/file.txt"))) {
           result = stream.collect(Collectors.joining());
        } catch (IOException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to read the whole file as String, there is no need to use a Stream. If you are using Java 11, you can just use [`Files.readString()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html#readString(java.nio.file.Path)):

```
try {
    String result = Files.readString(Paths.get("/home/user/file.txt"));
    System.out.println(result);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

If you need a Java 8 solution, see Holger's comment.

Comment: Since this question has been tagged with `[java-8]` and `Files.readString` requires Java 11, here's the alternative for completion: `String result;  try(Scanner s = new Scanner(Paths.get( "/home/user/file.txt"))) {  result = s.useDelimiter("\\A").next();  }`. You only have to care about the charsets; `readString` uses UTF-8, `new Scanner(Path)` uses the system's default. But both variants provide a version accepting a `Charset`.

Comment: @Holger yes, that is correct. Clarified that in my answer. Thanks for pointing that out.